# Send item link by email? (EDM SP2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, email, ribbon

Is there a way to directly send an item link by email?

I have a SP2013 based EDM. I know that docs URL are available in a popup, but I don't want to copy/paste link: I would like to be able to click on a button in ribbon/popup that opens email client with embeded link.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**: this is the current view that I need to improve: there should be either an email button in the popup view or in the ribbon when item is selected

[image: current view]

Comment: Edit: I need the button to be available in list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom action to the list callout according to [this](http://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-a-custom-action-to-a-callout-in-sharepoint-2013/) article.

In a nutshell:

```
function myCallback()
{
    var link = window.location; // for current item you can probably get this from  renderCtx, can't test right now
    var emailSubject = "email subject" // Here you can add article title, or just static string
    window.location = "mailto:?Subject=" + escape(emailSubject) + "&body=" + encodeURI(link)
});


function AddCustomAction (renderCtx, calloutActionMenu) {   
  // Add your custom action
  calloutActionMenu.addAction (new CalloutAction ({
    text: "Email",
    tooltip: "Email link to item",
    onClickCallback: function() { myCallback(); }
  }));

  // Show the default document library actions
  CalloutOnPostRenderTemplate(renderCtx, calloutActionMenu);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to say that I need the link to be available from the list view.

Comment: Would putting the button to system master page in that case work for you?

Comment: Nope... I think I need either injecting JS to the info popup window of an item or a custom action with a button in ribbon. But I don't know exactly how to manage it.

Comment: If you mean the popup dialog when you add/edit item, those forms you can modify using SharePoint Designer, it's either the NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx of the list.

Comment: I mean the popup dialog in the list view (see my post edit)

Comment: Ok, got it, rewrote my answer.

Comment: This works when added as snippet to the page thanks! I only have to inject it on feature activation.

Comment: Great! Did you figure out how to get current item URL?