# Sharepoint 2013 Custom action tokens - can I get a specific field from the current list item?

Tags: list, list-form, custom-actions, token

I'm trying to create a custom action for a list, that appears in the ribbon when viewing a specific list item. The list item has two fields that I want referenced in the custom action (email address and title).

In the custom action window, I pick "navigate to URL", and in there I want to write something like "mailto:{email}?subject={title}", where {email} and {title} are two fields from the currently viewed list item. Of course {title} and {email} aren't Sharepoint tokens, so what should I do there to make it work like that?

Comment: Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/93b47c9a-643b-473e-8111-afa342f18116/custom-action-to-email-item?forum=sharepointcustomization) and let me know if it helps. Also you can create a custom action as mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125125/send-item-link-by-email-edm-sp2013) and [here](https://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-a-custom-action-to-a-callout-in-sharepoint-2013/).

Comment: Thanks for the link! It seems like it's more or less what I'm looking for, but I've never coded anything for Sharepoint so I'm a total newbie here, I don't even know where I should put the code. The pages mention using the Script Editor web part, but web parts are put on pages, but I don't have a specific page for that, I want it to be in the popup window that displays a list element. I can't put webparts there, I think.

Comment: Yes, you can add the webpart on list view page. click on settings (gear) icon --> Edit Page --> Add webpart

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that! Just one more question, what's the best way to get a specific field of the currently viewed list item? The example has this line:

var emailSubject = "email subject" // Here you can add article title, or just static string

What should I put after "=" to get a specific field?

Comment: As per the link you can use any static string you want to give in subject line. to add the list item title dynamically I need to check how it can be done.

Comment: I have another problem :( I wanted to start with something that works, and then modify it to my use, so I copied and pasted the entire script from here: https://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-a-custom-action-to-a-callout-in-sharepoint-2013/

However, when I open the page and go to the javascript console, I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: SPClientTemplates is not defined